# cannot not get impi after installing 14.4 maas. cannot power on servers

Tags: maas

i am not getting any IMPI after installing ubuntu 14.4 LTS maas, during enlistment/commissioning of my servers. it was functioning in 12.4 but is not detecting it in or setting it 14.4. dell poweredge 1950 gen 3. maas cannot power servers on

i get the drop down menu with the options, but it does not set it automatically during enlistments/commissioning.

For anyone wondering, impi is how Maas/juju powers on physical servers,

Answer (score 0):

I'd get a bug filed here so the MAAS team can take a look:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/maas

There's been a lot of work done between 14.04 and 12.04 in the IPMI areas of MAAS and some older Dell machines might run into problems with getting their BMCs auto-configured.

Comment: need someone to provide a workaround to this if possible